# Values in numpy array behaving strangely

Tags: python, numpy

FIXED: Thanks chaps, y(t) not y(x)
I have code that is supposed to simulate the trajectory of a perfect object, no drag only gravity. 
The pastebin: https://pastebin.com/XknNBiJ9

Where I think the problem lies is in my function called evalPoly, as this is what populates the y values numpy array. The max value is correct for what I am expecting, however it happens way too soon in the array and the rest is very oversized negative numbers

```
def evalPoly(coefs, xs): #Y values messed up
    """
    @function: evalPoly
    @params:
        coefs;  The coefficients, an iteratable object (List, tuple, array)
        xs;     The x values, a numpy array  
    @returns:   result; a numpy array
    @purpose:   Evaluate at xs a polynomial with coefficients in coefs.
    """
    result = 0.0
    for coef in coefs[-1::-1]:
        result = result * xs + coef
    return result
```

And here is the calling function, in case my logic is not sound:

```
def trajectoryNoDrag(angleDeg,veloc,x0,y0): #Y values messed up
    """
    @function:  trajectoryNoDrag
    @params:    
        angleDeg (float); the angle of launch
        veloc (float); the initial velocity, x and y components
        x0 (float); the initial X pos
        y0 (float); the initial Y pos
    @returns:
        times (np.array); the time intervals
        xs (np.array); the x values
        ys (np.array); the y values
    @purpose:   Simulate the trajectory of an arrow
    """
    coefsX, coefsY = arrowPolys(angleDeg, veloc, x0, y0) #Store the coefs
    duration = quadSolve(coefsY)[0]     #flight duration
    tinc = duration * NUM_PER_SEC       #the incerments
    times = np.linspace(0,duration,tinc)    #The times
    xs = np.linspace(x0, coefsX[1] * duration, tinc)    #The x values
    ys = evalPoly(coefsY, xs)

    return times, xs, ys
```

The way that the variable 'coefs' is structured it is the three coefficients of a quadratic formula in the form [c,b,a].

Please help me figure out why the y-values are so screwy, they were working just fine and I don't know what I did to break the function. The x values and times are correct, they y's just suddenly done goofed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, given an array of `coefs = np.array([a,b,c])`, `evalPoly` is supposed to return `a*x**2 + b*x**1 + c`, right? That's what your description makes it sound like, but what you do is different than what would be expected.

Comment: The coefs are defined by the arrowPolys function, which is
`def arrowPolys(angleDeg, veloc, x0, y0):
    angleRad = np.deg2rad(angleDeg)
    return [x0, (veloc * np.cos(angleRad))], [y0, (veloc * np.sin(angleRad)),
            (-GRAVA/2)]`

Comment: I don't care what the `coefs` are supposed to be, but rather what `evalPoly`'s purpose is. given the array I stated, what should be returned if `xs = np.array([1])`? See my answer for what is the correct answer given my interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function of time, not of x. [y(t) not y(x)]. In other words, call `evalPoly(coefsY, times)` instead of `evalPoly(coefsY, xs)`.

```
def trajectoryNoDrag(angleDeg,veloc,x0,y0): #Y values messed up
    """
   @function:  trajectoryNoDrag
   @params:    
       angleDeg (float); the angle of launch
       veloc (float); the initial velocity, x and y components
       x0 (float); the initial X pos
       y0 (float); the initial Y pos
   @returns:
       times (np.array); the time intervals
       xs (np.array); the x values
       ys (np.array); the y values
   @purpose:   Simulate the trajectory of an arrow
   """
    coefsX, coefsY = arrowPolys(angleDeg, veloc, x0, y0) #Store the coefs
    duration = quadSolve(coefsY)[0]     #flight duration
    tinc = duration * NUM_PER_SEC       #the incerments
    times = np.linspace(0,duration,tinc)    #The times
    xs = np.linspace(x0, coefsX[1] * duration, tinc)    #The x values
    # your polynomial evaluation below is a function of time.
    ys = evalPoly(coefsY, times)

    return times, xs, ys
#-- End of File --#
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, after staring at this for too long basic logic eludes me. That fixed it.

Comment: You're welcome. It was good to take a look at some Physics for a change.

Answer (score 1):

Given my assumption of what `evalPoly` is supposed to do, here's a correct version of it:

```
def evalPoly(coefs, xs): #Y values messed up
    """
    @function: evalPoly
    @params:
        coefs;  The coefficients, an iteratable object (List, tuple, array)
        xs;     The x values, a numpy array  
    @returns:   result; a numpy array
    @purpose:   Evaluate at xs a polynomial with coefficients in coefs.
    """
    return np.polyval(coefs, xs)
```

Note that this is literally just the [polyval](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) function.

Comment: Gives the same values that my previous version did, so there must be something wrong with my logic elsewhere. My thought is that it now has to be either `arrowPolys` or `trajectoryNoDrag`. I don't think it is `arrowPolys` though because my `trajectoryDrag` function works just fine. This leads me to believe that `NoDrag` is messed up either in body or in the function calls that it makes

Comment: This assumes the `coefs` are in the form `[a,b,c]`, and then returns `a*x**2+b*x+c`. Maybe it's because you have `coefs` the wrong way? `np.flip(coefs, axis=0)` would fix that.

Comment: Still throwing bad values, Max: 39.65, Min: -851097.52